# Nodejs / Typescript: Using EventEmitter between multiple classes

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsyringe

I am using tsyringe as a dependency container and I have 2 classes. `AccountingService` and `TransactionService`. I am listening to the event triggered in `TransactionService` so that I can update the data in `AccountingService` using `accountingRepository` but on the method of updateTriggered, it shows an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')` on `accountingRepository`. Here is how my class look like:

AccountingService

```
@injectable()
class AccountingService {
 constructor(
   private accountingRepository: AccountingRepository,
   private transactionService: TransactionService
 ) {
    this.transactionService.on('updateTrigger', this.updateTrigger);
}

private async updateTrigger(data: any) {
   this.accountingRepository.findOne({ id: data.id })
}
}
```

TransactionService:

```
@injectable()
    class TransactionService extends EventEmitter {
     constructor(
       ...Some dependencies,
     ) {}
    
    private async someTransactionOccurred(data: any) {
       this.emit('updateTrigger', 'id', {});
    }
    }
```

`console.log(this)` in updateTrigger method is showing `TransactionService` object instead of `AccountingService`

Comment: `accountingRepository ` is working fine. I want to understand why `console.log(this)` is showing `TransactionService` instead of `AccountingService`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution. Changing it from

```
this.transactionService.on('updateTrigger', this.updateTrigger);
```

to:

```
this.transactionService.on('updateTrigger', this.updateTrigger.bind(this));
```

solved it. So, what I understand is that, it will be the object of transactionService if we dont explicitly use `.bind(this)`. Although, I am still waiting for the expert why is like this

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Yup, thats why it is not an accepted answer